# How can I make this a little less hideous? Python

Tags: python, redundancy

I am creating a simple program that prints a random productive activity. Here is a 'simplified' version of the program.

```py
import random

meditate = ['sitting down meditation','lying down meditation','standing meditation']
exercise = ['go for run','do yoga']
call_text_fam = ['call mom', 'call dad']

activity_list = [meditate, exercise, call_text_fam]

activity_list_spinner = random.randint(0,len(activity_list)-1)

meditate_spinner = random.randint(0,len(meditate)-1)
exercise_spinner = random.randint(0,len(exercise)-1)
call_text_fam_spinner = random.randint(0,len(call_text_fam)-1)

if activity_list[activity_list_spinner] == meditate:
    print(activity_list[activity_list_spinner][meditate_spinner])
elif activity_list[activity_list_spinner] == exercise:
    print(activity_list[activity_list_spinner][exercise_spinner])
elif activity_list[activity_list_spinner] == call_text_fam:
    print(activity_list[activity_list_spinner][call_text_fam_spinner])
```

This is going to get huge quickly so any ideas on how to clean this up would be awesome.

Comment: Try https://www.codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: also look into random.choice

Comment: You don't need to have `if` and `elif` in this situation for example. Assuming `activity_list[activity_list_spinner]` can only be one of those 3 things at once, you really just need to start each condition with an `if` statement. But I guess since you are using `random` anything is possible

Answer (score 3):

To illustrate Chris's comment, the second half can be reduced to just:

```
activity_list = [...]

print(random.choice(random.choice(activity_list)))
```